# android automatically deletes corrupt SQLite files

Tags: android, sqlite

When Android opens an SQLite file, and the file is corrupt, Android deletes the file.
As surprising as it may sound, this behavior is implemented clearly in the Android source code, leading to consternation and to this Android issue.

As a solution to it-

- Can't a recovery algorithm (aries) be implemented and can be added in the android source code.
- OR, it is better to use any other database like [Berkley DB Java Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index-093405.html), [H2 DB](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), or any other

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Maybe you should make it more clear what you actually asking. It is currently hard to tell because there is no question mark.

Comment: That seems odd, especially since SQLite has the option of fixing/trying to fix a corrupt file.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite already implements [a recovery algorithm](http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html) like ARIES (it's simpler because there is no write concurrency in SQLite). However, this doesn't help against errors in the flash storage; any other database would see similar corruption.

Apps already have to expect that their data vanishes, either when the user deletes it, or when the app is reinstalled. So it makes sense to use this as error recovery method; if Android would return I/O errors from every data access call, most apps would break because handling such errors has never been tested or not been implemented at all.